# Unable to execute RFECV over LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

My ML project is about "Loan Eligibility prediction"
For that I used data below : https://www.kaggle.com/code/sazid28/home-loan-prediction/data?select=train.csv
and my code is as shown :

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import \
    SimpleImputer, KNNImputer, IterativeImputer

from sklearn.preprocessing import \
    OneHotEncoder, OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV


df_train_original = pd.read_csv("train.csv.xls")

df = df_train_original.drop(df_train_original.columns[0], axis=1)

# Remplace 'Credit_History' by random value (0 or 1)

random.seed(0)

df['Credit_History'] = \
    df['Credit_History'].apply(
        lambda x: np.random.choice(df['Credit_History'].dropna().values)
        if np.isnan(x) else x)

X = df.iloc[:, :-1]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]

# Data pre-processing
numerical_feature, categorical_feature = [], []
for i in X.columns:
    if X[i].dtype == 'O':
        categorical_feature.append(i)
    else:
        numerical_feature.append(i)

imputer = IterativeImputer(random_state=0)
scaler = StandardScaler()
encoder = OrdinalEncoder()

# Replace categorical features with the most frequent value of the column
# Gender (-13) , Married (-3), Self_Employed (-32)
# LoanAmount (-22) Loan_Amount_Term (-14) Credit_History (-50)

numerical_pipeline = make_pipeline(imputer, scaler)
categorical_pipeline = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent'), encoder)

preprocessor = make_column_transformer((numerical_pipeline, numerical_feature),
                                       (categorical_pipeline, categorical_feature),
                                       remainder='passthrough')

clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, max_iter=df.shape[0])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.2,
                                                    random_state=0)
params = {
    'logisticregression__class_weight': [None, 'balanced'],
    'logisticregression__solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'],
    'logisticregression__C': np.linspace(0.001, 0.1, 30),
}

model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, clf)

selector = RFECV(model, step=1, min_features_to_select=2, cv=5)

selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

when I run the code I get :

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

I think that the data is not fitted and transformed before going through RFECV.

How to fix this?

Comment: sklearn objects can't take strings as input, you need to convert your object columns to numeric with OneHotEncoder or LabelEncoder

Comment: Hi @G.Anderson ... That’s  true !! and this is what I did but despite of it I got the error. If you look to my code RFECV took « model » as estimator. « model » is a pipeline using make_column_transform that transform categorical features using SimpleImputer and OrdinalEncoder

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to use the SimpleImputer _before_ encoding, and the imputer is the one that can't take string data

Comment: What I don’t understand is that my code is working when I remove 2 last lines and do model.fit .. it’s working as well when I make a GridsearchCV .. only when I use RFECV I got error

Comment: I tried to modify my code as you said : Encoding then Imputing and I got the same error

Comment: Could you post the entire error please?

Answer (score 0):

[`RFECV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFECV.html) does not work with a pipeline as the estimator, as it requires the estimator to expose either a `coef_` or a `feature_importances_`. Pipelines do not, and even if they did, there would be no guarantee that the feature importances of the final estimator correspond to the features input to the pipeline with arbitrary transformations in the intermediate.

What you can do is make the `RFECV` transformer an element of your pipeline between the preprocessing and the final estimator, ie

```
preprocessor = make_column_transformer((numerical_pipeline, numerical_feature),
                                       (categorical_pipeline, categorical_feature),
                                       remainder='passthrough')

clf_fs = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, max_iter=df.shape[0])
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0, max_iter=df.shape[0])
feature_selector = RFECV(clf_fs , step=1, min_features_to_select=2, cv=5)

model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, feature_selector, clf)
```